# ¿Como listar código como un string del tipo ‘0001’ en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

En `MySQL` base de datos `Northwind`, Tabla `Employees` y Tabla `Products`

•   Requiero poder listar código de empleado como un `string` del tipo `0001` (Tabla `Employees`) seguidamente poder listar los registros de la tabla `Products`.

•   En el campo cantidades por unidad (`quantityPerUnit`) de la tabla `Products` reemplazar la palabra `bottles` por `botellas`

Este es la sintaxis que estoy armando en este caso:

```
 select ProductID, ProductName, QuantityPerUnit
 from products
```

Lo que pretendo listar seria como esto:

```
Código  producto    cantidad por unidad
0001    Chang       24-12 oz botellas
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que tratas de obtener por favor considera explicar mejor

Comment: Gracias, la tabla employees me muestra en la columna de EmployeeID con vales 1,2,3,4, la idea es que estos los pueda listar como un numero de tipo String y lo pueda ver asi 0001, 0002 y sucesivamente, seguidamente necesito asociarlo al producto tabla products, campo ProductID y poder ver los productos asociados en el campo ProductName y muestre también el detalle asociado a los datos que están la columna del campo QuantityPerUnit  me entiende esta forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como quiero que aprendas no te daré todo en un solo comando, te voy a poner lo que ocupas en comandos separados los cuales podrás unir fácilmente, por ejemplo.

Para que el código de ProductID que quieres **rellenar con ceros** utiliza

```
SELECT LPAD(ProductoId,4,'0') FROM productos;
```

Para tu segunda pregunta puedes utilizar **replace**

```
select replace(QuantityPerUnit,"bottles","botellas")QuantityPerUnit from productos
```

Saludos.